# Send external http request from noir

Tags: clojure, noir

I have a need where in when a request is made to the server ,i want to fetch some data from external server for processing the present request.. Spend some time searching, but no luck.. I use **noir 1.2.2**

Is there any way i can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out myself.

Its quite simple, I did it using **clj-http-0.1.1.jar** which comes with noir...

```
(clj-http.client/post "uri" "params")
```